# Is it possible to add an item to the Nautilus right click menu in CentOS?

Tags: centos, gnome

I want to add an item to my right click menu, and run a command when a user clicks on it.

I'm using Centos 6.2, is it possible? If yes please tell me how I can do this.

Comment: This depends on which DE (desktop environment) and/or WM (window manager) you use, and not the distro.  CentOS offers a choice of DE, *most likely* yours is GNOME, but it could be something else.  So if you can determine that, it will help determine the answer to your question.

Comment: yes , its GNOME

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the tool `nautilus-actions` to do this. The main website is accessible here: http://www.nautilus-actions.org/. Should be in the standard repositories.

#### Installation

```
$ sudo yum install nautilus-actions
```

#### Usage

It can be invoked like this:

```
$ nautilus-actions-config-tool
```

It can also be invoked via pull downs: *System* -> *Preferences* -> *Nautilus Action Configuration*.

The main window looks like this:

[image: ss of actions]

When you invoke Nautilus you'll see it on the right context menu when right clicking on a file:

[image: ss of menu]

#### References

- [Using Nautilus Actions to Extend File Manager Functionality on Linux](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/368016-nautilus-actions-extend-the-functionality-and-flexibility-of-the-file-manage)

Comment: when i run the nautilus-actions-config-tool it says:t should i do ?
another instance of programming is already running , what should i do?

Comment: `ps -eaf | grep nautilus-actions`. Then kill it.

Comment: I killed it , but still that error apears , any idea?

Comment: I'm thinking that it's already running and is accessible from a menu directly in nautilus then, not sure where though, I'm looking.

Comment: Check under the System pull down, System -> Preferences -> Nautilus Action Configuration.

Comment: @AlirezaFallah - you're welcome, thanks for the question!

Comment: excuse me, I did whole thing and saved it , but it didn't apeared in the context menu

Comment: It shows up when you select a file in nautilus and right click on that file's context menu. You can use that tool to add items to other menus too, that was just an example, take a look at the tutorial link I references for more info.

Comment: this is not working on Centos 7 anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The same trouble on RHEL 6.4. No `nautilus-actions` instance is found in `ps aux`. This helped in my case:

`nautilus-actions-config-tool --non-unique`