# Gnome: How to disable or enable the "add to favorites" context menu

Tags: fedora, gnome, gnome3

I have a relatively fresh Fedora 20 install. Out of the box there is no "add to favorites" option in the context menu when clicking on a running program in the bar at the top.

I upgraded from Gnome 3.10 to 3.12 to see if that would solve the problem; it has not.

I can only assume that the Fedora maintainers have for some reason taken steps to remove this context menu item.

My question is: how can I add this context menu item back?

Edit: This option is also missing from the dash context menu; I'd like to restore it in at least one place.

Comment: There is a similar question, and the solution is `nautilus-actions` posted by slm which sounds like what you need: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91898

Comment: @geedoubleya Is this a nautilus thing? I honestly don't know if it is.

Comment: @don_crissti Regardless of whether you've seen it for the top menu, it's also missing from the dash menu in Fedora 20. I'd like to get it back in at least one place.

Comment: @geedoubleya This is not a duplicate because "use nautilus-actions" is not a complete solution to this problem, even if it is part of the solution.

Comment: Deleted duplicate comment...

Comment: @geedoubleya Do you know how to solve this with nautilus-actions, or are you just guessing that this is related?

Comment: No I have not done this myself, I just hoped it would be a useful pointer comment. I was going to try it on my laptop, but not had a chance yet.

Comment: @don_crissti Thank you for that. My assumption was in fact that the issue is with gnome-shell on my side (presumably due to Fedora meddling). I actually asked on the fedora desktop mailing list, and the answer came back that they haven't deliberately disabled this; however it's not available for programmes which are run from the commandline. (which is annoying).